# Any proposal where one can stake eos on behalf of certain accounts that have no eos at all?

Tags: cpu, resources, net

Is there any proposal that lets a parent account stake on behalf of child-accounts so those child accounts can freely send out tokens if they received them? My dilemma is if I created an account for my users of a dapp, they don't have the ability to interact with EOS as they don't have any eos staked. And if I gave them eos, what stops them from just sending my eos away?

Is there a way to "lease" my cpu/net to these child-accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any proposal that lets a parent account stake on behalf of child-accounts so those child accounts can freely send out tokens if they received them?

That's a native functionality of EOSIO via `$ cleos sytem delegatebw`

> `system delegatebw`
>
> **Delegate bandwidth**
>
> Positionals
>
> - `from TEXT` - The account delegating bandwidth
> - `receiver TEXT` - The account to delegate bandwidth from
> - `stake_net_quantity TEXT` - The amount of EOS to delegate for network bandwidth
> - `stake_cpu_quantity TEXT` - The amount of EOS to delegate for CPU bandwidth

As it can be seen above, `delegatebw` takes a parent account via `from` that is delegating the bandwidth and a receiver account via `receiver`. The `from` account can `undelegatebw` and retrieve their EOS, and the `receiver` cannot spend the EOS while being delegated bandwidth.

Comment: why can you not delegate (loan?) ram? Is there an example of how this look in a block explorer?

Comment: dan believes that in order to enable liquidity and discourage speculation for scarce resources such as ram, it's more efficient to use bancor algorithm instead of peer to peer trading. here is a tx hash for an `undelegatebw` d8bfb6f9e2a722ebca5a1399f34bbd3668968272197db715a0b11c6f512abbb3